# draw horizontal line after each line of a paragraph

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `<div>` of fixed height inside which there's a paragraph. Paragraph is long and I want to have a horizontal line under each line of the paragraph so that the line spans throughout the whole width of the `<div>`, like in the picture attached.

[image]

How can I do this?

I tried adding the `text-decoration: underline`, but I need the horizontal rule to occupy the whole width of the parent div.

Comment: what you suggest will only add `<hr>` only at the end of the paragraph, but i need that each line of paragraph is underlined.

Comment: also bad suggestion, because i need that the horizontal line to span through the whole width of the parent `<div>`. i thought i made it clear in the post.

Comment: for downvoters please give the reason!

Comment: @Paulie_D, i didn't think that i need to explain what i tried. i'll modify the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a similar answer to paulie_d, with a different approach: `background-size` does not have to be used.

it also uses `repeating-linear-gradient` with `em` values for start and stop colors  to be drawn accordingly to font-size and line-height.

clickable example to test different font-family and font-size:

```css
p {
  background:repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom, 
    transparent 1.7em, 
    currentcolor 1.7em , 
    gray 1.8em, /* any second color or textcolor */
    transparent 1.8em,
  transparent 3em);
  line-height:1.29em;
  padding:0.6em 0.5em;
  margin:1em;
  box-shadow:inset 0 0.5em  white, inset 0 0 0 0.4em white;/* to hide parts of the lines */
  border:solid;
  border-top:none;
  border-bottom:none;
}
/* test behavior with different  fonts */
p:hover {font-family:courier; font-size:1.1em;color:green}
p:focus {font-family:tahoma;font-size:1.2em;color:tomato}
p:active {font-family:georgia;font-size:0.9em;color:purple}
b {background:rgba(255,200,0,0.5)}
```

```html
<p tabindex="0"><b>click text to catch active and focus state</b>  <a href="#nogo">catch and remove focus from paragraph </a>tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
```

Box-shadow:inset is used to hide lines from the borders.

You can also use background-clip instead inset shadows:

```css
p {
  background:repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom, 
    transparent 1.7em, 
    currentcolor 1.7em , 
    gray 1.8em, /* any second color or textcolor */
    transparent 1.8em,
  transparent 3em);
  line-height:1.29em;
  padding:0.6em 0.5em;
  margin:1em;
  background-clip:content-box;
  border:solid;
  border-top:none;
  border-bottom:none;
}
/* test behavior with different  fonts */
p:hover {font-family:courier; font-size:1.1em;color:green}
p:focus {font-family:tahoma;font-size:1.2em;color:tomato}
p:active {font-family:georgia;font-size:0.9em;color:purple}
b {background:rgba(255,200,0,0.5)}
```

```html
<p tabindex="0"><b>click text to catch active and focus state</b>  <a href="#nogo">catch and remove focus from paragraph </a>tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a `repeating-linear-gradient`.

[image]

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

p {
  line-height: 1.2;
  background: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(
    top,
    transparent,
    transparent 95%,
    black 95%,
    black
  );
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(
    180deg,
    transparent,
    transparent 95%,
    black 95%,
    black
  );
  background-size: 1.3em;
}

div {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 1em auto;
  background:lightblue
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam rerum, explicabo repellendus animi aliquam facilis! Quidem nulla, odit nesciunt quis veniam corporis voluptates ipsum laboriosam autem! Eveniet, modi. Quasi facere, provident voluptatum
    laborum expedita impedit.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: hi, please have a look at the picture attached to my OP. the horizontal rules have to go under each paragraph line and occupy the whole width of the parent div.

Comment: That's what this is doing...?

Comment: for me it just draws a thick black line at the bottom of my paragraph, but i need under each line of the paragraph

Comment: thanks very much, but it still draws just a thick line at the end of the paragraph. please have a look at my picture attached, the lines are marked with red brush and written "horizontal rules".

Comment: Then your implementation seems to be off somehow. This does work and I have added an image of the result. Note that the `line-height` and `%` values might have to be adjusted for your requirements.

Comment: @Paulie_D, thanks very much. I was viewing it in firefox, and that is was the problem. it works.